# Как добавить на сервер базу данных MySQL из дампа .sql при помощи php?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть локальный сервер с готовой базой данных и её дампом для переноса её на другой сервер. Как сделать так, чтобы она автоматически восстанавливалась?

Comment: загрузите из командной строки sql или пхпМайАдмин. пхп тут лишнее звено. разве что вы делаете некий инсталлер, тогда понадобится разрешение на запуск `exec` и т.п. и все равно выполнить через шелл

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так:

```
exec("mysql -u$name -p$password $database < $file");
```

P.S. но всё же еще лучше делать всё в такой последовательности:

1. запускаете php скрипт, который
2. запускает скрипт python, который
3. запускает 
   P.P.S. а почему бы просто не залогиниться из консоли в mysql и не исполнить команду там?

   ```
   source [way_to_file]
   ```

(где вместо [way_to_file] нужно подставить путь к файлу, без кавычек).